# How do I retrieve Console.log ran inside of a New Funtion()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

If I'm creating an anonymous function with the new Function() constructor, how would I grab the console logs from inside of it?

For example:

```
value = "console.log('test');";
response = new Function(value)();
```

response is undefined because there is not return statement in this function.
Is there any way for me to find stream the console.log output from this function?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you expect to “grab”? `console.log` returns `undefined`. Why do it this way to begin with? Where does the value `"test"` come from?

Comment: Logs are in the logs. Are you asking how to log somewhere *else* besides the default stdout/stderr?

Comment: Sorry, I see the confusion now. My bad.
To be more clear:  I'm making an interactive IDE that runs on my localhost as a demo.

I want the code to run and display the output. In order to display the output I need to store it somehow.

Comment: You may use `eval("console.log('test')")` with caution as it could be a security concern. [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: You can overwrite `console.log`, but `"console.log('test');";` doesn't contain a return statement. There is no way that `new Function(value)();` returns anything. Are you looking for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lkcnf3vo/